# Simple SQL Server SELECT Not Working With Date

Tags: datetime, select, sql-server-2012

I have a simple table that has 3 columns that I'm concerned with

- TargetUnits (real)
- TargetDate (datetime)
- ProductID (int)

When I run the following `SELECT`, I get a number of datetimes on the day of 1015-12-10. This works great and I get the results elow

```
SELECT 
    [TargetDate], [TargetUnits] 
FROM 
    [TaktBoards].[dbo].[TargetPlot] 
WHERE 
    [ProductID] = 2 
    AND [TargetDate] > '2015-12-10 00:00:00'  
ORDER BY 
    [TargetDate] DESC
```

Output:

```
TargetDate  TargetUnits
--------------------------------
2015-12-10 23:45:00.000 50
2015-12-10 23:30:00.000 49.15254
2015-12-10 23:15:00.000 48.30508
2015-12-10 23:00:00.000 47.45763
2015-12-10 22:45:00.000 46.61017
2015-12-10 22:30:00.000 45.76271
2015-12-10 22:15:00.000 44.91525
2015-12-10 22:00:00.000 44.91525
2015-12-10 21:45:00.000 44.06779
2015-12-10 21:30:00.000 43.22034
2015-12-10 21:15:00.000 42.37288
2015-12-10 21:00:00.000 41.52542
2015-12-10 20:45:00.000 40.67797
2015-12-10 20:30:00.000 39.83051
2015-12-10 20:15:00.000 38.98305
2015-12-10 20:00:00.000 38.98305
2015-12-10 19:45:00.000 38.13559
2015-12-10 19:30:00.000 37.28814
2015-12-10 19:15:00.000 36.44068
2015-12-10 19:00:00.000 35.59322
2015-12-10 18:45:00.000 34.74576
2015-12-10 18:30:00.000 33.8983
2015-12-10 18:15:00.000 33.05085
2015-12-10 18:00:00.000 32.20339
2015-12-10 17:45:00.000 32.20339
2015-12-10 17:30:00.000 32.20339
2015-12-10 17:15:00.000 31.35593
2015-12-10 17:00:00.000 30.50847
2015-12-10 16:45:00.000 30.50847
2015-12-10 16:30:00.000 29.66102
2015-12-10 16:15:00.000 28.81356
2015-12-10 16:00:00.000 27.9661
2015-12-10 15:45:00.000 27.11864
2015-12-10 15:30:00.000 26.27119
2015-12-10 15:15:00.000 25.42373
2015-12-10 15:00:00.000 24.57627
2015-12-10 14:45:00.000 23.72881
2015-12-10 14:30:00.000 22.88136
2015-12-10 14:15:00.000 22.0339
2015-12-10 14:00:00.000 22.0339
2015-12-10 13:45:00.000 21.18644
2015-12-10 13:30:00.000 20.33898
2015-12-10 13:15:00.000 19.49153
2015-12-10 13:00:00.000 18.64407
2015-12-10 12:45:00.000 17.79661
2015-12-10 12:30:00.000 16.94915
2015-12-10 12:15:00.000 16.94915
2015-12-10 12:00:00.000 16.94915
2015-12-10 11:45:00.000 16.10169
2015-12-10 11:30:00.000 15.25424
2015-12-10 11:15:00.000 14.40678
2015-12-10 11:00:00.000 13.55932
2015-12-10 10:45:00.000 12.71186
2015-12-10 10:30:00.000 11.86441
2015-12-10 10:15:00.000 11.01695
2015-12-10 10:00:00.000 10.16949
2015-12-10 09:45:00.000 9.322034
2015-12-10 09:30:00.000 8.474576
2015-12-10 09:15:00.000 7.627119
2015-12-10 09:00:00.000 7.627119
2015-12-10 08:45:00.000 7.627119
2015-12-10 08:30:00.000 6.779661
2015-12-10 08:15:00.000 5.932203
2015-12-10 08:00:00.000 5.084746
2015-12-10 07:45:00.000 4.237288
2015-12-10 07:30:00.000 3.389831
2015-12-10 07:15:00.000 2.542373
2015-12-10 07:00:00.000 1.694915
2015-12-10 06:45:00.000 0.8474576
2015-12-10 06:30:00.000 0
```

However when I run this `SELECT` (just adding the `[TargetDate] < '2015-12-10 03:56:00'`) I get no results.

```
SELECT 
    [TargetDate], [TargetUnits] 
FROM 
    [TaktBoards].[dbo].[TargetPlot] 
WHERE 
    [ProductID] = 2 
    AND [TargetDate] > '2015-12-10 00:00:00' 
    AND [TargetDate] < '2015-12-10 03:56:00' 
ORDER BY 
    [TargetDate] DESC
```

What am I doing wrong? I want to get all the records for December 10th that are less than 3:56 in the afternoon.  Please help.  :)

Andy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[TargetDate] < '2015-12-10 03:56:00
```

when your smallest record is
`2015-12-10 06:30:00.000 0`

which is bigger than your comperand. maybe you mean

```
[TargetDate] > '2015-12-10 03:56:00
```

Comment: OMG!!  That's it.  The ol' 12 verus 24 hour clock.  :)  Thank you very much for pointing this out.  I totally missed that.  I needed 15:56 and not 3:56.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want this:

```
TargetDate < '2015-12-10 15:56:00' -- 24-hour clock
```

Another option is to use a literal format that allow you to specify `am/pm`.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx

Answer (score 0):

3 pm in the afternoon should be expressed as 15:00.  Your data, if that's all of it, has nothing in the 0 to 03:00 range